# Есть ли в .NET какой-нибудь ConnectionDialog?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, ado.net

Если в .NET какой-нибудь `ConnectionDialog`, где пользователь может выбирать сервера с БД и каталоги?

Нашел какой-то класс- `DataLinks`, но вроде он COM'овский, а так же на NUGET какую-то библиотеку 2010 года.

Есть чего-нибудь из коробки или более свежее?

Comment: А зачем ему такой диалог, если детали подключения - это частное дело каждого поставщика СУБД. У кого-то и понятия такого "каталог" нет. Не будут же они для каждой БД свой диалог делать, тем более что они все конкуренты ихней MS SQL

Comment: @Sergey, ну в DataLinks, в зависимости от поставщика меняется само окно. Например, при выборе JET выбирается путь к файлу и пароль, а при MS SQL, сервер и каталог.

Comment: Надо смотреть на какую технологию рассчитан datalink. Их много уже было, может в какой-нибудь предусмотрено чтобы поставщик драйвера бд, поставлял мета-информацию, по которой даталинк может построить диалог, или сам диалог или его элементы. А может разработчикам даталинк было просто не лень перебрать все возможные базы. dot net использует свои драйвера-коннекторы, а даталинк допустим предназначен для odbc-драйверов, где действительно для каждой базы каким-то образом получается индивидуальный диалог.

Comment: Если такой диалог нужен исключительно для MS SQL Server (судя по тегам вопроса), то реализовать его самостоятельно, по крайней мере, для WinForms - не составит большого труда.

А вообще есть вроде унифицированные диалоги для построения ConnectionStrings.

Comment: посмотри вот этот пост:
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/857399/SQL-Server-Connection-Dialog-Extensible мне кажется это то что тебе нужно

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Из коробки (почти) существует решение под названием Microsoft Data Connection Dialog:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

О том, как правильно его готовить - [есть статья на Хабре](https://habrahabr.ru/post/167067/). Но она старая, и не очень актуальная в связи с не очень работающими ссылками.

Тем не менее, в MSDN есть [описание данного класса](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.data.dataconnectiondialog.aspx), а так же [фабрика](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.data.dataconnectiondialogfactory.aspx) для создания таких окон.

Так же [на английском SO есть вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6895251/6935496) ([с ответом](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6895428/6935496)) про этот диалог.

Еще оно [живет в NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DataConnectionDialog/), но более ранней версии — датировано 2011 годом. Какую именно версию использовать (и использовать ли) — решать вам.

Более того, есть более свежие исходные коды данного проекта, которые живут теперь на [GitHub](https://github.com/kjbartel/ConnectionDialog) (на момент написания данного ответа последние изменения там — март 2015 г).
Судя по названию файлов с исходниками, данный диалог поддерживает:

- подключение к разным версиям MS SQL Server;
- подключение к Oracle;
- подключения к другим источникам через ODBC и OLE DB.

*IMHO: Лично я бы использовал версию с Гитхаба.*

Answer (score 7):

Интерфейс OleDB это поддерживает, где-то видел пример на с++. На с# это можно через ADO так:

```
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;


public string GetConnectionString(string str)
{
string connectionString=string.Empty; // возвращаемая строка подключения
object cn=null, // ADODB.Connection
       ud=null; // MSDASC.DataLinks

  try
  {
    Type AdoDbConnectionType=Type.GetTypeFromProgID("ADODB.Connection");
    Type MSDascDataLinksType=Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(new Guid("{2206CDB2-19C1-11D1-89E0-00C04FD7A829}"));
    // создать COM объекты ADODB.Connection и MSDASC.DataLinks
    cn=AdoDbConnectionType.InvokeMember(null, BindingFlags.CreateInstance, null, null, new object[0]);
    ud=MSDascDataLinksType.InvokeMember(null, BindingFlags.CreateInstance, null, null, new object[0]);

    AdoDbConnectionType.InvokeMember("ConnectionString", BindingFlags.SetProperty, null, cn, new object[]{str});
    if((bool)(MSDascDataLinksType.InvokeMember("PromptEdit", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, ud, new object[]{cn})))
    { // нажали кнопку ОК:
      connectionString=(string)(AdoDbConnectionType.InvokeMember("ConnectionString", BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, cn, new object[0]));
    }
  }
  catch{ /* обработка ошибок */ }
  finally
  { if(cn!=null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(cn);
    cn=null;
    if(ud!=null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(ud);
    ud=null;
  }
  // вернуть строку подключения
  return(connectionString); 
}
```

Источник http://www.sql.ru/forum/120264/ne-zauchivayte-stroku-konekta#952795
В str можно заносить предустановленые свойства для линка, плюс в Provider записать имя провайдера (формате ODBC например MSDASQL алиас это MSSQL ).