# Как выполнить JavaScript на c#?

Tags: javascript, c#

Хочу выполнять js на уровне сервера IIS. Увидел что с COM обьектами можно работать через GetTypeFromProgID [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/582538/17974). Написал аналогичный код, он даёт ошибку

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
public class Demo {
static void Main() {
  string code =@"var WScript = new ActiveXObject('WScript.Shell');";
  Type TScript=Type.GetTypeFromProgID("ScriptControl");
  object sc = /*тут ошибка*/TScript.InvokeMember(null, BindingFlags.CreateInstance, null, null, new object[0]);
  TScript.InvokeMember("Language", BindingFlags.SetProperty, null, sc, new object[]{"JavaScript"});
  TScript.InvokeMember("AddCode", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, sc, new object[]{code});
}
}
```

Ошибка 80040154 Class not registered
StackTrace ошибки:

```
Необработанное исключение: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80040154): Сбой при получении производства объектов класса COM для компонента с CLSID
{0E59F1D5-1FBE-11D0-8FF2-00A0D10038BC} в результате следующей ошибки: 80040154.
   в System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnl
y, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandle& ctor, Boolean& bN
eedSecurityCheck)
   в System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean fillCache
)
   в System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipVisib
ilityChecks, Boolean fillCache)
   в System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder bind
er, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
   в System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder
 binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture)
   в System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags bindingFlags, Bin
der binder, Object target, Object[] providedArgs, ParameterModifier[] modifiers,
 CultureInfo culture, String[] namedParams)
   в Demo.Main()
```

Так как возникли споры между 32 и 64 то добавлю что пробовал собирать и под 32 и под 64

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\csc.exe js.cs
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe js.cs
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\csc.exe js.cs
```

Ошибка та же.

До сегодня выполнял **ScriptControl** на с++, на vbs и даже js-js мосты делал и без проблем.
Но я не понимаю что значит класс не зарегистрирован. На этой же машине проверяю код на js (пример js-js мост):

```
var sc = new ActiveXObject("ScriptControl");
sc.language = "JavaScript";
sc.AddCode("var WScript = new ActiveXObject('WScript.Shell');");
sc.AddCode("WScript.Popup(1);");
```

А этот код работает. Чем же c# .net2.0 не нравится ScriptControl? Ещё, глянул реестр - там всё ок, и GUID из ошибки соответствует ScriptControl.

Если можно - без импорта библиотеки показать решение. Подключать лишние dll на сервере не хочу (у меня с ними проблема на x64).

Почитал статью [Как боротся с  80040154](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7197506/how-to-repair-comexception-error-80040154) покажу реестр
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Classes\CLSID\{0E59F1D5-1FBE-11D0-8FF2-00A0D10038BC}\InprocServer32` 
    по умолчанию `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msscript.ocx`. А ключ в `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\` отсутствует. Может надо как-то дополнительно указать что эта COM библиотека является 64-битной?

Если на x64 `csc.exe /platform:x86  js.cs` работает, и на 32-битной машине код работает отлично, то вопрос тогда такой. Как 32-битную COM библиотеку подключить к x64 NET под IIS?

Comment: А почему именно .NET 2.0?

Comment: Разрядность-то совпадает?

Comment: @PavelMayorov одна и та самая машина. х64. Win7. По идее винда должна 32-bit библиотеку определять и линковать к 64 коду...

Comment: @nick_n_a не должна. 32х-битная библиотека не может линковаться к 64х-битному коду.

Comment: А как же шлюзы? А как же ie подключает библиотеку javascript? Я попробовал собрать под другие версии - не получается.

Comment: @PavelMayorov  `csc.exe /platform:x86  js.cs` помогло если собрать под 32 бита. А 32-битную библиотеку к NET х64 подключить можно?

Comment: @nick_n_a я уже отвечал на этот вопрос.

Comment: попробуй посмотреть в сторону JavaScriptServices (https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices), если я не ошибаюсь, то ты там из шарпа можешь запустить node.js передать ему скрипт, нода его выполнит, а тебе вернет результат.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я попробовал несколько вариантов использования библиотеки и пришёл к следующим выводам:

1. Под ASP.NET IIS вызов JavaScript обработчика идёт без проблем как на x64 так и на x86. Почему так - обьяснить не могу.
2. Так как данная библиотека является 32-битной то на x64 код работать не будет, как вариант, можно сделать 32-битную сборку `csc.exe /platform:x86  js.cs`.
3. На x86 код работает хорошо.