# C# Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel Некорректное подключение сборки

Tags: c#, .net, excel, office, office-interop

Создаю пустой проект Console App, целевая платформа .NET 6. Добавляю ссылку на COM-сборку *Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library*, подключаю - `using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;`. С какого то момента некоторые методы и свойства класса [`Excel._Workbook`](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.tools.excel.workbook?view=vsto-2017), которые я использовал ранее, перестали существовать. Например стал недоступен метод [`_Workbook.SaveAs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.tools.excel.workbook.saveas?view=vsto-2017), вместо свойств [`_Workbook.Worksheets`](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.tools.excel.workbook.worksheets?view=vsto-2017#microsoft-office-tools-excel-workbook-worksheets) и [`_Workbook.ActiveSheet`](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.tools.excel.workbook.activesheet?view=vsto-2017#microsoft-office-tools-excel-workbook-activesheet) появились методы `get_Worksheets` и `get_ActiveSheet` соответственно. Что могло привести к такому поведению и как это можно исправить, не переписывая код в старых проектах (замену `SaveAs` вообще даже найти не могу)?

- Visual Studio 17.4.4
- Microsoft Office 2303 16.0.16227.20202

Comment: _Office 2303_ - сообщение из будущего? А вообще, почему вы отказались от ClosedXML и решили использовать Interop?

Comment: _"Office 2303 - сообщение из будущего?"_ - [Нет](https://ibb.co/FnnQxFy). Стоит рассмотреть вариант перехода к ClosedXML, но в настоящий момент нужно исправить то что есть.

Comment: Если ли строгая необходимость использовать .net core, можете проверить что например при использовании .net 4.8 проблема сохраняется? Есть подозрение что не очень хорошо офисный интероп работает с dotnet.
Возможно стоит вот ещё взглянуть: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58130770/735446

Comment: _"Если ли строгая необходимость использовать .net core, можете проверить что например при использовании .net 4.8 проблема сохраняется?"_ - Проблема исчезает при использовании .NET Framework, решение по ссылке не помогло. Есть сложности в переносе: `SocketsHttpHandler` доступен только в .NET, я использую этот класс для отправки пакетов через определённый дополнительный IP-адрес (IP алиас).

Comment: Ещё... как вариант решения проблемы, если проблема исключительно из-за платформы - вы можете сделать что бы одна платформа была рабочей, а другая вспомогательной. Вторая по команде через named-pipe или сокет или субд может принять пакет (пакет можно сериализовать) и обработать в excel по нужному алгоритму, а рабочую не трогать особо.

Answer (score 1):

В с# есть возможность подключать COM-библиотеки напрямую. Долгий путь, не знаю поможет ли вам, но возможно поможет.

Как я это делал (на примере ScriptControl [Как выполнить JavaScript на c#?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/597717/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-javascript-%d0%bd%d0%b0-c)).

1. Открываете системный реестр. В ветке HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT Находите там ваш класс.
   Чаще всего работает application. Например "Excel.Application" или "Excel.Application.12" (версия офиса который у меня).

   ```
    Type TExcel=Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Excel.Application");
    object Excel = TExcel.InvokeMember(null, BindingFlags.CreateInstance, null, null, new object[0]);
   ```

Тут прокоментирую, COM библитотеки бывают двух видов, 32-битные, 64-битные, и двойные. Если выдаст 80040154 ошибку, и ProgID есть в реестре... то ему не нравится сборка.

2. В либо гуглим в интернете библиотеку, или вариант 2, найтиде файл excel.exe и вытрусите с него с помощью программы Exescope, ResourceHacker раздел TypeLib, и попробуйте получить пару свойств с помощью COM методов. Они будут совпадать с теми, которые вы ранее использовали, но доступ к ним через своеобразную рефлексию будет. Ниже привожу нерабочий пример, что бы показать в какую сторону копать

   ```
   TScript.InvokeMember("Language", BindingFlags.SetProperty, null, sc, new object[]{"JavaScript"});
   TScript.InvokeMember("AddCode", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, sc, new object[]{code});
   TScript.InvokeMember("SaveAs", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, excelworkbook, new object[]{code});
   ```
3. Если 1,2 получилось, остаётся написать обвертку которая подменит те методы которые вы используете прямым пробросом в COM-библиотеку.

Возможно кто-то уже для c# делал обвертку с# - COM Excel.Application, может погуглив удастся такое найти.

Возможно доступ к исщезнувшему методу удастся восстановить через рефлексию, как показано выше в п.2.

Вообще ситуация странная, может это какой-то баг который позже исправят... COM-библиотека это самый "нулевой" уровень доступа excel, если microsoft что-то испортили в промежуточной библиотеке, то COM - должно работать.